# Did Kirk really show how to make gunpowder in the episode "Arena"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, captain-kirk

I remember seeing this episode when it was first aired. I was 13 and always wanted to get the charcoal, sulfur and saltpeter.

Comment: Follow-up question - is it possible to build a rudimentary lathe using natural materials like rocks and plants?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - Get off the line, Guy!

Comment: I'm glad I didn't find this when I was 13 and watching Star Trek http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Gunpowder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Not quite.

While those are the proper components, his method was flawed -- this has been covered in multiple shows -- including the primary go-to for such things, Mythbusters. Unfortunately, I can't find a full video of the test. For that [you'll have to go to the website](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos).